# Updating a Field in the Current Selection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I have some address points selected for which that I want to update the address field based upon the row in the selection. How do I figure out the name of the selection taable to pass to arcpy.UpdateCursor()?

Comment: Could you edit your post to explain more what you're trying to do? Also, what version of ArcMap are you using?

Comment: I am using ArcGIS 10.1. I have a selection of points that refer to the placement of buildings in a larger feature class of building points. I want to put the row number of the selected rows in the building address field. Is it possible to place the row of the selection into a field of a group of selected rows? I don't know what the name of the table is since I only want to change the building number field in a few (selected) rows of a table.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply isolating selected features for use with an update cursor, it should be as simple as -

```
use gp.MakeFeatureLayer("featureclass", "featlyr")
cursor = gp.UpdateCursor("featlyr", "", "", "BLDADDRESS")
row = cursor.next()
while row:

    rownum = row.getValue("OID_or_NUM")
    row.setValue("BLDADDRESS", rownum)
    cursor.updateRow(row)
    row = cursor.Next()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only do that from a Python Add-In.

[pythonaddin.GetSelectedTOCLayerOrDataFrame()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/The_pythonaddins_module/014p00000021000000/)